# get drawing cache always null android

Tags: android, image

I have Code like this ,

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash2);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


        image_book = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_image_book);
        harga_book = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_harga_book);
        nama_book = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_nama_book);
        des_book = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_des_book);
        frmCaptureThis = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_book);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        final Cursor cur = db.getFood();

        if (cur.getCount() != 0) {

            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    food_name = cur.getString(1);
                    food_price = cur.getString(2);
                    food_des = cur.getString(3);
                    food_kalori = cur.getString(4);
                    nama_book.setText(cur.getString(1));
                    String value = cur.getString(2);
                    char chars[] = value.toCharArray();
                    if (value.length() > 2) {
                        value = Character.toString(chars[0])
                                + Character.toString(chars[1]) + ","
                                + Character.toString(chars[2]);
                        Log.e("value", value);
                    }
                    Log.e("food name", cur.getString(1));
                    harga_book.setText(value);

                    des_book.setText(cur.getString(3));

                    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(cur.getString(5));
                    Log.e("path image", cur.getString(5));

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                        image_book.setBackground(d);
                    } else {
                        image_book.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
                    }

                    frmCaptureThis.post(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Bitmap bmp = merge();
                            saveToLocal(bmp);
                            i++;
                        }
                    });



                } while (cur.moveToNext());

            }
            cur.close();

        }

        db.close();    

        }
```

this code is set view in content relative layout like textView and set Background for relative layout, after this view has set , I want to make this relativelayout parent to be image using merge() . This is method merge()

```
public Bitmap merge() {


        View v1 = frmCaptureThis;

        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap merge = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        return merge;
    }
```

frmCaptureThis is relativelayout parent , but why , always return null in v1.getDrawingCache , any solution please?? thanks

Comment: When are you executing the above code? `onCreate`? is the `RelativeLayout` empty or something?

Comment: I executing in onCreate, do u have solution?

Comment: You should not do it `onCreate` as the view has not been measured and drawn yet. Put this inside `onWindowFocusChanged` or post you full `onCreate` method and I will give an alternate solution

Comment: Umm.. looks good to me since you post a runnable. Try adding line `buildDrawingCache()` after `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);`! It that doesn't work then, make a _test_ button and then try running this code when _test_ button is clicked and see if there is any difference.. let me know what happens..

Comment: @AmulyaKhare I've tried add buildDrawingCache() and it return null , But when using test button , it work , but I want to use it in every view that create by cursor , any solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42553/discussion-between-amulya-khare-and-user1920582)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem maybe because the `layout` has not been measured and drawn yet. Try the following way:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash2);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


    image_book = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_image_book);
    harga_book = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_harga_book);
    nama_book = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_nama_book);
    des_book = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_des_book);
    frmCaptureThis = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_book);

    frmCaptureThis.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            processFromDatabase();
        }
    });
}

private void processFromDatabase() {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    final Cursor cur = db.getFood();

    if (cur.getCount() != 0) {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                food_name = cur.getString(1);
                food_price = cur.getString(2);
                food_des = cur.getString(3);
                food_kalori = cur.getString(4);
                nama_book.setText(cur.getString(1));
                String value = cur.getString(2);
                char chars[] = value.toCharArray();
                if (value.length() > 2) {
                    value = Character.toString(chars[0])
                            + Character.toString(chars[1]) + ","
                            + Character.toString(chars[2]);
                    Log.e("value", value);
                }
                Log.e("food name", cur.getString(1));
                harga_book.setText(value);

                des_book.setText(cur.getString(3));

                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(cur.getString(5));
                Log.e("path image", cur.getString(5));

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                    image_book.setBackground(d);
                } else {
                    image_book.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
                }

                Bitmap bmp = merge();
                saveToLocal(bmp);
                i++;        

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }
        cur.close();
    }
    db.close();    

}
```